# DataGrid row values not changing properly

Tags: c#, datagrid

I am trying to implement the KeyDown event for my DataGrid where when the user presses *'Enter'*. The changes made to the row will be saved to the database and then automatically move to the next row.  However, after setting some break points I found that the fields that I change before pressing *'Enter'* are not being updated when I try to pull the record using SelectedItem.  Here is the KeyDown method:

```
private void dataGrid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        var wasError = false;
        var item = new LibraryRecord();
        try
        {
            item = (LibraryRecord)dataGrid.SelectedItem;
        }
        catch(Exception a)
        {
            wasError = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot insert on last line.", "Error");
            dataGrid.SelectedIndex = dataGrid.Items.Count - 2;
        }
        if (!wasError)
        {
            using (var context = new LibraryEntities())
            {
                try
                {
                    //save changes to row
                    var record = context.LibraryRecords.FirstOrDefault(q => q.ID == item.ID);
                    record.Date = item.Date;
                    record.Description = item.Description;
                    record.Name = item.Name;
                    record.NegNumber = item.NegNumber;
                    record.BoxNumber = item.BoxNumber;
                    context.SaveChanges(); //TODO - properties aren't changing unless you leave the row then come back to it
                }
                catch (Exception a)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("System Message:\n" + a.Message, "ERROR");
                }
            }
            //move to next row
        }
    }
}
```

The ItemsSource for dataGrid is a `List<LibraryRecord>` that is cast to `System.Collections.IEnumerable`.

Is there something I'm missing to make sure that the data in the row is updated before I pull it in the method and set it to the variable `item`?

Comment: So you're saying when you press enter, the values you entered into the fields aren't being kept, so you're updating it with the same values, is that right?

Comment: @DubDub yes that's right.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but in the using statement, you're creating a brand new 'LibraryEntities()' object, and then you're trying to get the record from that context you've just created with no objects inside. Did you put this in as a temporary measure?

Comment: @DubDub no I didn't. It hasn't caused any problems anywhere else in the project where I've used it though (and I use it many times).  Is there a better way to do it? I'm still pretty new to this